# Get LinkedIn CDN image url for ugcPosts

Tags: linkedin-api

For many ugcPosts the thumbnail URL returned is an external URL which is often invalid. For instance, one post is a link to a Facebook page and the URL returned by LinkedIn is an expired Facebook CDN url. I also tried the shares api but the resolvedUrl is the same.

Is there any way to request the image URL hosted on the LinkedIn cdn?

FYI: For now we are hitting the website directly and getting the og:image but this isn't guaranteed to work and can still lead to inconsistencies between what is shown on LinkedIn and what we show in our application (e.g. different images).